# Sizing a window AC for bedroom, but with extenuating circumstances

Tags: windows, air-conditioning, cooling

I'm looking to install a window AC in my son's bedroom, which is about 120 sq ft.  The guides that I'm reading suggest a 5000 BTU unit due to the size.  However we live in the high desert where the summer temperature gets > 100 degrees (F) at times during the summer.  Also he has several reptile terrariums in his room that require lamps which also heat up his room.  In this case would using a 6000 BTU AC unit be more appropriate?

My 180 sq ft. home office/spare bedroom is in the room next to his.  I use a 6000 BTU unit and it chills this room no problem.  So thinking of getting the a simular sized unit, but don't want to oversize if that's going to cause problems.

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: An estimate of the terrarium lamps power needed.

Comment: About 3 100 - 150 watt bulbs.

Comment: Have you ever heard the term "solar gain"?  Where are the rooms relative to the sun? (exposed west, tree-shaded, etc.) What color are the surfaces which face the sun?

Comment: @Frank 300W are ~1000BTU/h, 450W are ~1500 BTU/h . Whatever number you come to for the room, just add 1500 BTU/h for the lamps.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I was thinking the same thing, orientation of the room is an important consideration. Not only that, but quality (insulation ) of windows as well as the amount of insulation in the walls.

Comment: One more comment.  Although probably not an issue in your area due the "high desert" area, you probably have very low humidity, but in other places, with high humidity, over-sizing the unit can lead to icing up and / or not enough run time to dehumidify the air, which leaves kind of a clammy feeling. It's a balancing act.   This is just a comment , not an answer bc I just don't know enough about your situation to give a good answer.

Comment: either will work, there's not a huge difference between them. I would opt for the bigger one as it's greener and could be used more elsewheres later if needed. You can keep the fan on low while cooling and off when idle to extend cycle time if you're worried about short cycling. But on the other hand, that 5000 one might be working a higher duty cycle than expected with all that added heat, which is non-ideal. That's why I call it a wash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go larger, I have installed many heating and cooling systems and when the systems are running properly the AC will cycle more often, icing is more of a problem with very high humidity and or low air flow and this can happen even in the desert on a hot day if the filters are dirty reducing the air flow while the system is working at its maximum cooling capacity.

I find customers are happier being able to turn the thermostat up a little verses when the room is still hot with the AC at its lowest setting running full blast. An over sized unit may cost a little more because it may cycle the compressor on and off more often but this cost will be a small percentage of the annual cost to run and you have a better chance of keeping the room comfortable.